# El login devuelve el mensaje de usuario y contraseña incorrectos, pese a que los datos son correctos

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Me encuentro trabajando con Node.js y estas son las dependencias que instalé para realizar el login:

- Mysql
- express-session
- express-myconnection
- dotenv
- bcryptjs

El inconveniente que tengo es que al hacer login me dirije a "Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecta" teniendo en la BD todo correcto. He consultado diferentes documentaciones y no hallo el error.

Comparto el código:

```
// Metodo para la autenticacion
router.post('/auth', async (req, res) => {
    const nombre = req.body.nombre;
    const pass = req.body.password;
    const salt = 8;
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(pass, salt);
    if (nombre && pass) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM registro_usuarios WHERE nombre = ?', { nombre: nombre, password: pass }, async (error, results) => {
            bcrypt.compare("B4c0/\/", passwordHash, function (error, results) {
                if (error) throw error;
                // Si la cuenta existe
                if (results.length > 0) {
                    // Autenticar al usuario
                    request.session.loggedin = true;
                    request.session.nombre = nombre;
                    // Redirigir a la página de inicio
                    res.render('/');
                } else {
                    res.send('Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecta');
                }
                res.end();
            });
        });
    } else {
        response.send('Por favor ingresa Usuario y Contraseña!');
        response.end();
    }
});
```

Comment: No crees que son demasiadas dependencias para un simple login???

Comment: @LordXedriantheHigher tiene una dependencia para encriptar, una para manejar la sesión, una para la base de datos, y otra para manejar las variables de entorno. Según tú ¿Qué está de mas?

Comment: @Brayam según tengo entendido, `compare` recibe la contraseña en texto plano y el hash guardado en la base de datos. Deberías llamarla como `bcrypt.compare(pass, results.password, callback)`. No entiendo por que hasheas la contraseña antes y colocas un texto hardcodeado sin usar lo que traes de la base de datos.

Comment: Solo me asombro la idea de usar tantas dependencias para un login. Yo tambien uso logins y no necesito usar cookies ni sessionStorage o localStorage (hablo de JS).

Comment: @LordXedriantheHigher pues me imagino la poca seguridad tendrán esos logins. Porque las contraseñas necesitas guardarlas encriptadas y para eso necesitas una dependencia. Para conectarte a la DB necesitas otra dependencia. Para manejar la sesión también una dependencia y también  necesitas el driver de la base de datos.  `sessionStorage` y `localStorage` son cosas del `front end`, creo que no entendiste la pregunta. Esta pregunta es de nodejs (backend). Estás confundiendo las cosas.

Comment: Yo uso el patron de diseño modulo para crear una función auto-invocable q contiene en su interior una variable llamada SesionID. Como la variable es privada, no hay forma de modificar esta variable desde fuera de la funcion q la define (las cookied si se pueden alterar)

Comment: Yo uso bases de datos. Loa passwords se almacenan usando bcrypt con una salt de valor 20 (bastante alta). Cuando el login es correcto, la variable sesionID del frontend (inalterable desde afuera) se modifica con un token que viene siendo el id del usuario segun un auto_increment en mysql (encriptado usando el algoritmo sha_256). Y se abre un canal por SSE para agregar ese usuario a la liata de los activos actualmente.

Comment: Cada vez q se haga una operacion de insert / update / delete en la bd, se envia wl token desde el frontend, se desencripta en el backend y se determina si existe el usuario correspondiente. Todo esto para determinar los niveles de acceso de cada usuario segun los roles de esos usuarios. El token se genera usando una clave de 64 caractetes alfanumericos aleatorioa q se actualiza todos los dias automáticamente (esta clave solo es valida durante un dia)

Comment: No me vengas a hablar de seguridad por favor!!!

Comment: Todo lo hago sin frameworks. Yo usos lenguajes puros (js y Python) sin librerias de terceros

Comment: @LordXedriantheHigher la pregunta es basada en nodeJS, no Python. Y no está en cuestionamiento las dependencias que decide usar en su proyecto, sino brindarle una solución o ayuda en el inconveniente que se le presenta.

Comment: Intenta hacer una comparación manual imprimiendo por consola la contraseña que trae de la BD y la que encriptas para que puedas evaluar si son iguales, seguramente hay algún problema en la encriptación de la contraseña ingresada al logear. Al no ver como estás haciendo la encriptación cuando generas el usuario, se me ocurre este método de la vieja escuela.

Comment: Hola Jaime Menéndez Gracias por la respuesta, voy a seguir el consejo. Te comento que soy nuevo con Node.js por eso presento el caso a la comunidad.